# In TeXstudio code: increase font size of theorem environments *only*

Tags: texstudio

In the "syntax highlighting" tab of the options menu, I can increase by, say, 150% the size of all environments, which is great for quickly scrolling through my large TeX documents. I am hoping that somehow I can limit this font size increase (and, if possible, also a color change) to only certain environments that I call "theorem" environments, like \begin{theorem} or \begin{corollary}, etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not supported with the current implementation of TeXstudio. You can post an issue to the its [issue tracker](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues).

Comment: I see...is there some tex/coding software that allows this?